# AS3 Z-INDEXING Movie CLips

Tags: actionscript-3, z-index

**Hello to all
I have 2 movieclips on stage with instance names: green & orange.
I am using this code to timeline frame 1 to bring forward each item is clicked:**

```
MovieClip.prototype.bringForward = function():void{
    var currentDepth = this.parent.getChildIndex(this);
    if(currentDepth<this.parent.numChildren-1){
        this.parent.setChildIndex(this, currentDepth+1); 
    }
}


green.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clicked);
orange.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clicked);

function clicked(e:MouseEvent){
    e.target.bringForward();
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to load this from an external .as file in this:

```
package  {


    public class Main {



        public function Main() {

        }



    }

}
```

I tried a lot of times but i didn't had any luck.

**I tried this:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.accessibility.AccessibilityProperties;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class Main {




        public function Main() {


            addListeners();




        }



MovieClip.prototype.bringForward = private final function():void{
    var currentDepth = this.parent.getChildIndex(this);
    if(currentDepth<this.parent.numChildren-1){
        this.parent.setChildIndex(this, currentDepth+1); 
    }
}




        private final function addListeners():void
        {

            green.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clicked);
            orange.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, clicked);

        }





    private final function clicked(e:MouseEvent)
    {
    e.target.bringForward();
    }





    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the prototype thing.  Make a function on the class like this:

```
private function bringForward(clip:DisplayObject):void{
    var currentDepth:int = getChildIndex(clip);
    ... rest of your swapping logic
}

private function clicked(event:MouseEvent){
    bringForward(event.target as DisplayObject);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but i got an error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:DisplayObject.

Comment: import flash.display.DisplayObject

Comment: or change to (clip:MovieClip) since you are working with MovieClips (both will work)